# How to fetch the particular string values from a file

Tags: c#

I have a text file ,which contains like this


and i need to fetch the values of datafield ie with in "" and also need to fetch the value of header ie with in "" in other file.
in new file i need only
AREA_CODE    Area Code.

how can i solve this?

Comment: Yes you can do that using 2 possible way read line use `String functions` . Read line use `Regex` but I would go with `String` functions.

Comment: how does a line of your text file exactly look like? give a real example

Answer (score 2):

You could use `File.ReadLines` + string methods:

```
string dataPattern = "Data-field=\"";
string headerPattern = "Header=\"";
var allDataFieldsAndHeader = File.ReadLines(pathToFile)
    .Where(l => l.IndexOf(dataPattern, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 
            &&  l.IndexOf(headerPattern, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 )
    .Select(l =>
    {
        int index = l.IndexOf(dataPattern, 0, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) + dataPattern.Length;
        int endIndex = l.IndexOf("\"", index);
        string dataField = l.Substring(index, endIndex - index);
        index = l.IndexOf(headerPattern, 0, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) + headerPattern.Length;
        endIndex = l.IndexOf("\"", index);
        string header = l.Substring(index, endIndex - index);
        return new { DataField = dataField, Header = header };
    });
```

Tested with this sample file:

```
  Data-field="DataField Value1"   Header="Header Value1"
foo bah
  data-field="DataField Value2"   Header="Header Value2"

 Data-field="DataField Value3"   header="Header Value3"
baz
```

Output:

```
foreach (var x in allDataFieldsAndHeader)
    Console.WriteLine("DataField: {0} Header: {1}", x.DataField, x.Header);
```

Result:

```
DataField: DataField Value1 Header: Header Value1
DataField: DataField Value2 Header: Header Value2
DataField: DataField Value3 Header: Header Value3
```

Answer (score 0):

try this add each line of textfile to a list

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
if(File.Exists(path))
{
    // Read the file and display it line by line.
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\yourtextfilepathhere.txt");
    while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
       lines.Add(line);
    }
    file.Close();
}
```

Then you can take each List item and you are saying there is something like

```
Data-field="value" and Header="value"
```

so you can check the corresponding value

```
 var line1 = lines 
        .Where(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Contains(Data-field));
```

then take the respective value after the string

**OR**

Save text file values as array list
**Example**

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"yourtextfilepath");
```

then use split function with your strings i mean  `Data-field and Header` then take the value after each string 
Note : i hope you know what is the value to be and what will come after that value so based on that split it and save to string then you can easily save this to another files .

Answer (score 0):

Regex is the absolute simplest solution.

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(File.ReadAllText("filename"), "(?<Name>Data-field|Header)=\"(?<Value>.*?)\"")
```

This will leave you hopefully with to entries.
For simplicity you can convert the results to a dictionary

```
var results = matches.Cast<Match>().ToDictionary(x => x.Groups["Name"].Value, x => x.Groups["Value"].Value);
```

Results should now contain `["Data-field"]` and `["Header"]`.

**edit:** since there seems to be something scary about regular expressions, I will explain

`(?<Name>Data-field|Header)=\"(?<Value>.*?)\"` is the regular expression, or the *pattern* we are looking for. It contains two major parts:

`(?<Name>Data-field|Header)`

and
`\"(?<Value>.*?)\"`

The first one says that we are looking for a group. We call this group Name (this is what `?<Name>` means). Is Data-field|Header. This literally means 'Match "Data-field" OR "Header"'.

Between these two is a equals sign. It means just that: match an equals character here.

The next part `\"(?<Value>.*?)\"` is the one that matches the value part. \" means match ". We just escape it since " doesn't mean anything to regex.

`.*?` means 'match zero or more of any character but use the shortest match you can find'.

Period simply means 'any character' and the asterisk means 'zero or more of the preceding patternt' while the question mark means 'non-greedy'. The non-greedy part is important because otherwise it could match across several values:

`abc="123" newValue="4567"`

Could result in Value being `123" newValue="4567"` because the default behaviour is greedy, and there can be more than one correct match for this expression.

The advantage of using regular expressions here is that maintenance is very simple compared to a manual parser.

Regular expressions is a text search tool though, so trying to build a complex parser using it will drive you mad, so use it for what it is best for: searching for simple regular expressions in text documents.

Comment: _"absolute simplest"_ only if you're familiar with them.

Comment: If you're on stackoverflow unwilling to learn new things then I would suggest that you are in the wrong place.

Comment: It's always good to learn, therefor people ask   questions and even with answers you learn a lot. But i just wanted to point out that _"absolute simplest"_ is  subjective. What is simple for you is difficult and cryptic for others.

Comment: I understand. I added a explanation of how it works. Thanks for the input.